# Getting Cocoa method completions in Sublime Text 2

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, editor, sublimetext

I've been playing with Sublime Text 2 the last few days and was wondering if anyone out there has had any success getting Cocoa method completions working yet? Is there a plugin (or in-progress project to create one) out there?

Any general comments on using Objective-C in Chocolat or Sublime Text 2 would also be welcome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an in-progress Sublime Text package that connects to clang to get autocomplete data called [SublimeClang](https://github.com/quarnster/SublimeClang) I've not managed to successfully get it to work totally with Cocoa/UIKit Dev, but here's a screenshot

[image: Screenshot ofSublime Clang]

and my [options](https://gist.github.com/1490994), that are a start

Comment: Where are you supposed to add those options?

Comment: Unsure as it's been over a year, you'll have to read the docs: https://github.com/quarnster/SublimeClang

Answer (score 1):

In MacVim I use a plugin called Cocoa.vim which haves useful python scripts that generates a classes and methods files for autocompletion. I didn't try so much with ST2, but may be is posible to create a sublime-package or sublime-completions file with all this data.

For the moment, I only create a sublime-completions file with some snippets. If I find a way to make this work, I will tell you.

Answer (score 1):

I let my SublimeClang configuration options if helps anybody. I've already some of the autocompletions working:

```
"options":[
        "-Wall",
        "-isystem", "/Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/include/",
        "-isystem", "/Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/",
        "-I/usr/lib/clang/3.1/include/**",
        "-I", "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include/",
        "-arch","armv7",
        "-isysroot", "/Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk",
        "-D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000",
        "-ferror-limit=0"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here. A quick visit to the Sublime forums didn't turn up any leads nor did Google. It looks as though method completions for Objective-C aren't currently part of the default install nor available via 3rd-party quite yet.

Answer (score 0):

This user http://b.rthr.me/wp/?p=368 claims to have gotten SublimeClang working.  I may report back myself once I try it...